# multiple `async getter(s)` in one object acting as a cache

Tags: javascript, getter

**Update2:** The following works but not quite

```js
const obj = {
    cached_a: 0,
    cached_b: 0,
    cached_c: 0,

    get a() {
        if (this.cached_a == 0) this.cached_a = getA();
        return this.cached_a;
    }
}

const getA = function() {
    console.log('calcing...')
    return 25;
};

console.log('1: ' + obj.a);
console.log('2: ' + obj.a);
```

In my program, the value is not calculated the second time but sent back from the cache.

```sh
$ node get-set.js 
calcing...
1: 25
2: 25
```

For one, my `getA()` has to be `async`. But, I understand that ES6 doesn't allow `async getters`. If that is correct, I would appreciate a better way of achieving the above (given that `getA()` *has* to be `async`.

Second, how do I use multiple `getters` (for `b` and `c` as well)?

---

**Update1:** The `getA()` (and hopefully, other getters) get values from the server (this is all browser side), and I don't want that to happen if the value has been retrieved once and is cached in the browser.

---

I am trying to understand and implement `getter/setter` in an object that is going to act as a cache for values returned from `async` processes.

```js
'use strict';

// my desired pseudo-object with incorrect code
const obj = {
    a: 0,
    b: 0,
    c: 0,

    get a() {
        if (this.a == 0) this.a = await getA();
        return this.a;
    }

    get b() {
        if (this.b == 0) this.b = await getB();
        return this.b;
    }

    get c() {
        if (this.c == 0) this.c = await getA();
        return this.c;
    }
};

const getA = async function() { … };
const getB = async function() { … };
const getC = async function() { … };
```

Obviously, several problems with the above:

- can't have multiple `getters` (or can I?);
- can't have `getters` named the same as the property as that results in a recursive call (how do I make the act of getting transparent for the user?)

What is a better way to implement this?

Comment: There are ways to do this, but it seems to me this is a good case of the XY problem (www.xyproblem.info). When a promise is resolved, waiting for it shouldn't bother you as extra cost -- there is no calculation involved. If you want to instead cache *obtaining* a promise -- that's another thing. What do your `getA` etc function actually do? This looks to me like a very contrived example of doing something that should be done differently. In any case, your `get a()` shadows `a: 0` -- you are declaring the same property, in fact.

Comment: yes, I now understand the *shadow* problem, and my updated question corrects for it. Thanks for pointing that out. The `getA()` (and hopefully, other `getters`) get values from the server (this is all browser side), and I don't want that to happen if the value has been retrieved once and is cached in the browser.

Comment: As for your bullet-point questions: a getter creates a new property description for the same property descriptor (name), so if the property already exists, the new description will take its place ("shadowing" wasn't a good verb for this, "overwritten" is). In your case `this.a` calls the getter instead of accessing the value you assigned with `a: 1`. And your getter is obviously recursive since it evaluates `this.a`. Getters in JavaScript are just property definitions with distinct evaluation semantics, but the property descriptor still must be unique among all property names in the object.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, but at the risk of helping you out with a problem you don't have (I suspect your overall application design has flaws you should correct elsewhere), I'll address your immediate problem.

Your mistakes are rooted in the fact that your property descriptions -- whether expressed as e.g. `a: 1` or `get a() ...` use the same property descriptor (commonly referred to as "name") so your getter redefines what e.g. `this.a` will refer to, overwriting the previous property description (`a: 1`) and the same applies to the other properties `b` and `c`.

I also want to state that your apparent idea of caching promises leads me to think that perhaps some of your assumptions are wrong -- when a promise resolves, the value is already cached internally. A promise is designed to be settled (resolved or rejected) only once, but every time you attach a callback though the `Promise.prototype.then`, the [settled] promise will call your callback with the internally cached value. `await` is little more than syntactic sugar where the interpreter internally runs your code in order, but rest assured whenever an `await` expression is evaluated, a cached value that was "resolved" once will be used.

What I am trying to tell you is that caching promises does not make sense.

What you *can* cache is procedure evaluation. You start by assuming that a procedure call (without arguments, to make caching simpler) will always return the same value, which you then may safely associate with the procedure, in your cache:

```
const cached = (() => {
    const cache = new WeakMap();
    return (procedure) => {
        var result = cache.get(procedure);
        return result || (cache.set(procedure, result = procedure()), result);
    }
})();
```

Now, if you have a costly operation encapsulated in a function, say `request_foobar`, instead of using the `request_foobar()` expression which will perform a lengthy operation that returns the same result every time anyway, you can use `cached(request_foobar)` expression, which will get you the previous result from cache, if there is a cache hit, or, if there isn't, call the procedure and return the cached result.

The implementation of `cached` depends on so-called "closure" functions -- the procedure assigned to the `cached` constant may access objects (variables, constants, etc) in its outer scope, including the actual cache (a map of results based on procedure references).